# Control of a program by use of Serial to-USB switch

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, usb, usbserial

We want to control a program (written in VB) by pressing a switch attached to a serial to USB adapter. When pressed a certain function in the program will be activated. In order to achieve this we need to poll the relevant com port, continuously in the comm_event of the serial port and call the said function.  We tried by connecting a push button switch between the transmit and ground pins of the adapter, to change the state of the input buffer. It works sometimes, but misses most of the time. So it seems we need to create a long pulse train to keep the input buffer state last long enough to detect any change. Is there any gadget available for something like this? What kind of simple electronics can achieve this task.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer by Robert Grier (the author of [Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to Serial Communications, 4th Edition ISBN 1-890422-28-2](http://amzn.com/1890422282)) I am grateful for his help and therefore sharing this with all interested.

Connect one side of the switch to the DTR output (pin 4 of the connector) and the other side of the switch to the DCD input (pin 1)

Drop the Comm control from the Toolbox you your form and add a single Label.  In code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    On Error Resume Next
    With MSComm1
        .CommPort = 3  'use the actual port number that is created when you install your USB adapter
        .PortOpen = True
        .DTREnable = True
        If .PortOpen = False Then MsgBox "Unable to open serial port."
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()

    With MSComm1
        If .CDHolding = True Then
            Label1.Caption = "Switch On"
            Label1.BackColor = vbGreen
        Else
            Label1.Caption = "Switch Off"
            Label1.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the computer doesn't have a serial port, so you are plugging the USB adapter into the USB port on the PC then trying to read some condition that you create on the RS-232 side of the adapter? I would look at the flow control pins DTR/DSR etc. Do you have an external source of power available? RS232 expects typically +/- 12v. Depending on what you're trying to achieve and your circumstances you could also look at adding a hardware serial port to the PC, or using a hardware USB interface such as this one : http://www.maplin.co.uk/usb-experiment-interface-board-42857

Comment: Hello Peter. There is a USB port on the computer. Idea using a serial to USB adapter is to be able to access IO pins to create a detectable signal change at the input buffer so that we can use this state change to trigger a function in our program. The adapter is powered by the computer.

Comment: Hi - Then the rest of my answer applies - use the flow control pins as I said and as spelt out more fully in Sparers answer. Personally as you're using an extra bit of hardware anyway, I'd still be drawn towards using a USB-to-hardware adapter as per my link; that is exactly what it's designed to do, whereas using a serial port, even though quite acceptable still feels like a bit of a bodge. That's just me. A more solid reason is - depending on your application - the USB adapter gives you a lot more input and output lines to utilise should your application expand to need them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but some variation on...

```
Private WithEvents com As New IO.Ports.SerialPort

Private Sub com_PinChanged(sender As Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialPinChangedEventArgs) Handles com.PinChanged

    Dim pin As IO.Ports.SerialPinChange = e.EventType

    If pin.DsrChanged Then
        MsgBox("DSR changed")
    End If

End Sub
```

...should work. Change the state of pin 6 on a DB9 connector. You can access other pins also using this method.

Comment: Hello Spares. This would be very valuable. But we are using VB6. IS there any equivalent code in VB6 for this routine?

Comment: I don't have VB6 installed but it should be a matter of checking the .ComEvent for 4 (comEvDSR) when .OnComm is called. You might have to change the .Handshaking property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259410(v=vs.60).aspx